# SAN SSL certificates for MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, ssl

For our database client authentication, we need subject alternative SSL certificate. Can we just create SAN variant or we need to buy it from the vendor?

I'm trying to secure a MongoDB cluster with SSL encryption. For our cluster member's internal authentication & client authentication I'm using the same certificate. Now I need subject alternative certificate for our client authentication. We already have SSL certificate from Comodo, Can we just generate a variant from it or we need to buy the variant?
https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/configure-x509-client-authentication/#addx509subjectuser

Answer (score 0):

The MongoDB doc talks about RFC2253 based client authentication certificate. Comodo's Personal Authentication certificatee might be the one you need. Although i'm not quite sure about this "RFC2253 formatted subject" line mentioned in the doc, best to check with COMODO.

[https://www.instantssl.com/ssl-certificate-products/personal-authentication-certificate.html][1]